# Collapsing Columns in R Easy Version

Tags: r, tidyverse, forcats

I know there are some questions similar to this one already, but I am a beginner in r and I just can't understand the answers to them! If you are able to provide a simple, not so complicated answer to my question I would really appreciate it!!

I am trying to collapse categories in a column in my data frame, the summary of which looks like this (category = n):

```
1-Self = 62
2-Mother = 0
3-Father = 43
4-Grandfather = 142
5-Grandmother = 17
6-Uncle = 1
7-Brother = 2
8-Husband = 5
9-Aunt = 0
10-Sister = 2
11-CommunityInfluencer = 1
12-ReligiousFigure = 0
13-Other = 4
14-N/A = 9
```

I would like to combine categories 6-14, but they're all in the same column, how do I do this? If you could provide a structure for how to code this simply I would really appreciate it!

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Cath and welcome, I'm sure someone would be happy to help but to be able to do so we need to better understand your data, could you please `dput(head(yourdataframe, 10))`

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, `forcats::fct_lump` will probably do the job here https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_lump.html

Comment: @NColl, this is very helpful. Would you mind sharing an example of using forcats? I don't quite understand how to use it.

Comment: @ChuckP I have included this in my dataframe. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `forcats::fct_other`, you can specify which categories you want to combine into an "Other" category

As an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

drop_cats <- c("Naboo", "Stewjon")

starwars %>%
  mutate(homeworld =  fct_other(homeworld, drop = drop_cats)) 

A tibble: 87 x 13
   name       height  mass hair_color   skin_color eye_color birth_year gender homeworld species films  vehicles starships
   <chr>       <int> <dbl> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr>  <fct>     <chr>   <list> <list>   <list>   
 1 Luke Skyw…    172    77 blond        fair       blue            19   male   Tatooine  Human   <chr … <chr [2… <chr [2]>
 2 C-3PO         167    75 NA           gold       yellow         112   NA     Tatooine  Droid   <chr … <chr [0… <chr [0]>
 3 R2-D2          96    32 NA           white, bl… red             33   NA     Other     Droid   <chr … <chr [0… <chr [0]>
 4 Darth Vad…    202   136 none         white      yellow          41.9 male   Tatooine  Human   <chr … <chr [0… <chr [1]>
 5 Leia Orga…    150    49 brown        light      brown           19   female Alderaan  Human   <chr … <chr [1… <chr [0]>
 6 Owen Lars     178   120 brown, grey  light      blue            52   male   Tatooine  Human   <chr … <chr [0… <chr [0]>
 7 Beru Whit…    165    75 brown        light      blue            47   female Tatooine  Human   <chr … <chr [0… <chr [0]>
 8 R5-D4          97    32 NA           white, red red             NA   NA     Tatooine  Droid   <chr … <chr [0… <chr [0]>
 9 Biggs Dar…    183    84 black        light      brown           24   male   Tatooine  Human   <chr … <chr [0… <chr [1]>
10 Obi-Wan K…    182    77 auburn, whi… fair       blue-gray       57   male   Other     Human   <chr … <chr [1… <chr [5]>
# … with 77 more rows
```